# Composer "chmod(): No such file or directory" with bin directory

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install my Symfony2 app on koding.com

Trying to install my vendors via php composer.phar update, I run into the following issue, installing doctrine/orm:

```
Installing doctrine/orm (2.3.x-dev 4d9f24b)
Cloning 4d9f24b2eef3af3a3e76c773994c19bbb0706f88

[ErrorException]
chmod(): No such file or directory
```

I tried to debug with -v and found out that the following line is causing this issue:

```
composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:217
```

In there I see that this issue is related to the bin directory. I have set (S2 default) the bin-dir to "bin". The bin directory is also in place within my project, but somehow composer does not find it, when trying to change the chmod. I have used this setup on several windows machines and also on c9.io.

Comment: This seems to be related to this composer issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1270

Comment: I don't think this question will receive an answer anymore. The Github issue was fixed and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved due to fix on github: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1270